# Split a string in java and map to value with another string

Tags: java, regex, string

i need to split a string in java and map it to city ,country and continent

```
String s = "mumbai| india - Asia";
String b ="{city}|{country}-{Continent}"
```

where: `|` and `-` are special characters

output:

```
city - mumbai
country - india
continent - Asia
```

Comment: What you tried... Post your tried code

Comment: Is there a space between `|` and `india`, or is this a typo?

Comment: yes there can be space. My Logic is this<br> 1) using regex get a separator<br> 2) extract the text from string s 3) using regex get mapping from b and the produce the output

Comment: Should be straightforward using one regex with three capture groups.

Comment: @user3205867 why you do not use replace? "| " ---> "|" and " - " --->"-"

Comment: Do you want to parse `{city}|{country}-{Continent}` string also?

Answer (score 2):

why dont you use named capturing groups ?

```
(?<city>[^|]*)\s*\|\s*(?<country>[^-]*)-\s*(?<continent>[\w\s]*)
```

demo here :

https://regex101.com/r/kZ4tQ7/1

see the match information on the right hand side

Comment: Nice regex-page! Been looking for something similar for ages.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try

```
String s = "mumbai| india - Asia";
String[] splitString = s.split("|");
String city = spiltString[0];
String secondSplit[] = splitString[1].split(" - ");
String country = secondSplit[0];
String continent = secondSplit[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this.

 String s = "mumbai| india - Asia";
 String b ="{city}|{country}-{Continent}";

 String city = s.split("\\|")[0];
 String country = s.split("\\|")[1].split("-")[0];
 String cont =s.split("\\|")[1].split("-")[1];


 String cityT = b.split("\\|")[0];
 String countryT = b.split("\\|")[1].split("-")[0];
 String contT =b.split("\\|")[1].split("-")[1];



System.out.println(cityT.replace("{", "").replace("}", "") +" - " + city); 
System.out.println(countryT.replace("{", "").replace("}", "") +" - " +  country); 
System.out.println(contT.replace("{", "").replace("}", "") +" - " + cont);
```